# Is this Frobenius Monad left exact? Does it preserve equalizers?

Tags: ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics, monads

[In this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04324)  we see a Frobenius Monad in example 5.2.  Suppose we take Hilb as the underlying category.  Is this functor left exact?  Does it preserve equalizers?

Comment: It seems we are both looking for examples of monads that preserves equalizers...